# Flexible string parser

Tags: c++, performance

I am writing an mathematical expression parser, and therefore I need fast way to edit any string in any imaginable way.

---

**My current solution:** (compilable code)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include <algorithm>
#include <list>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class is_whitespace {
public:
    inline bool operator() (const char & c)
    {
        return ( ' ' == c) || ('\n' == c) ||
               ('\r' == c) || ('\t' == c) ||
               ('\b' == c) || ('\v' == c) ||
               ('\f' == c);
    }
};

inline void erase_whitespaces(string & expr) {
    expr.erase(remove_if(expr.begin(), expr.end(), is_whitespace()), expr.end());
}

class FindDelim {
private:
    string & out_delim;

public:
    inline FindDelim(string & out) : out_delim(out) {}

public:
    inline bool operator()(char & c, string & delim) {
        if (string(&c, delim.size()) == delim) {
            out_delim = delim;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
};

inline void split_string(
    vector<string> & output_str,
    vector<string> & output_del,
    const string::iterator & str_beg,
    const string::iterator & str_end,
    const vector<string>::iterator & del_beg,
    const vector<string>::iterator & del_end)
{
    string delim;
    size_t delim_len;

    string::iterator last = str_beg;
    string::iterator next = str_beg;
    while ((next = find_first_of(last, str_end, del_beg, del_end, FindDelim(delim))) != str_end) {
        delim_len = delim.size();

        output_str.push_back(string(&(*last), distance(last, next)));
        output_del.push_back(string(&(*next), delim_len));

        last = next + delim_len;
    }
    output_str.push_back(string(&(*last)));
}

inline void split_string(
    vector<string>         & output_str,
    vector<string>         & output_del,
    const string::iterator & beg,
    const string::iterator & end,
    vector<string>         & delims)
{
    return split_string(output_str, output_del, beg, end, delims.begin(), delims.end());
}
inline void split_string(
    vector<string>         &  output_str,
    vector<string>         &  output_del,
    const string::iterator &  beg,
    const string::iterator &  end,
    vector<string>         && delims)
{
    return split_string(output_str, output_del, beg, end, delims.begin(), delims.end());
}

inline void split_string(
    vector<string> & output_str,
    vector<string> & output_del,
    string         & expr,
    vector<string> & delims)
{
    return split_string(output_str, output_del, expr.begin(), expr.end(), delims.begin(), delims.end());
}

inline void split_string(
    vector<string> &  output_str,
    vector<string> &  output_del,
    string         &  expr,
    vector<string> && delims)
{
    return split_string(output_str, output_del, expr.begin(), expr.end(), delims.begin(), delims.end());
}

inline void split_string(
    vector<string> &  output_str,
    vector<string> &  output_del,
    string         && expr,
    vector<string> &  delims)
{
    return split_string(output_str, output_del, expr.begin(), expr.end(), delims.begin(), delims.end());
}

inline void split_string(
    vector<string> &  output_str,
    vector<string> &  output_del,
    string         && expr,
    vector<string> && delims)
{
    return split_string(output_str, output_del, expr.begin(), expr.end(), delims.begin(), delims.end());
}

int main()
{
    string expr("[X] += 2 + 100 + 32 + 231 -= 123 + 532");

    // Erase white space:
    erase_whitespaces(expr);
    cout << expr << endl;

    // Split expresion:
    vector<string> splited_str;
    vector<string> splited_del;
    split_string(splited_str, splited_del, expr, { "+=", "-=" });

    // Print result:
    for (vector<string>::iterator it = splited_str.begin(); it != splited_str.end(); ++it) {
        cout << *it << endl;
    }

    // Hold:
    getchar();
}
```

---

1. How can I improve this code in terms of performance?
2. using `string(char *, size_t)` constructor to convert `string::iterator itr` (`*itr` is a `char`) hurts my eyes and soul... Is there any better way of performing this conversion?
3. I will want to switch output containers from `vector<string>` to `list<string>` (REASON: calling `list<string> myList; myList.insert()` will be faster.).
4. I know that `FindDelim()` function object will perform out-of-bounds read, at the end of the string. But I think I can live with it. (prove me wrong?)

---

Function `split_string()` in the example has been called in a loop until the given time duration has passed. Measurement result is average value from every call.

> measurement duration: 180      [sec] 
>   measurement result 1: 1895.690 [ns]  
>  
>   measurement result 2: 1878.571 [ns]

Comment: Use flex/bison to write a real expression parser.

Comment: @LokiAstari Where's the challenge in that?

Comment: If you are going to be repeatedly editing this presumably long string then you would want to use a data structure called a [rope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rope_(data_structure)).

Comment: I disagree with @LokiAstari; if you want to write a *correct* expression parser, I don't think flex/bison is up to the task. Standard infix expression notation deals with contextually-sensitive operator precedence, operators with differing associativity, and a whole mess of other problems. Source: [I wrote one](https://github.com/davedelong/DDMathParser)

Comment: @DaveDeLong flex/bison deal with these issues and a whole bunch more very easily and in a fraction of the space you have used for your linked parser. A lesson in using the correct tools for the job.

Comment: Don't pass `const char &` (reference) if you can pass `char` by value - a `char` is considerably smaller, and probably has already been moved into a CPU register. In is_whitespace::operator() you might consider to test for `>32`and do an early return, otherwise there will be a *lot* of tests being made with each non-whitespace  (by the way: there is nothing wrong with *isspace*; some implementations even utilize a lookup table to achieve maximum performance!).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You probably don't need to modify the input string.  Assuming that whitespace is allowed only between tokens (i.e. that user's aren't expected to write `532` as `5 32` or `+=` as `+  =`), then each token can be returned as a `std::string_view` - provided you're willing to keep the string alive for as long as you use any of the views.

---

Prefer to use `const_iterator` types when you won't be modifying the values; I think that all the iterators in `split_string()` can be const iterators if you change the signature of `FindDelim::operator()` to accept its arguments as reference to const:

```
bool FindDelim::operator()(const char & c, const string & delim)
{
    if (string(&c, delim.size()) == delim) {
        out_delim = delim;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

inline void split_string(
    vector<string> & output_str,
    vector<string> & output_del,
    const string::const_iterator & str_beg,
    const string::const_iterator & str_end,
    const vector<string>::const_iterator & del_beg,
    const vector<string>::const_iterator & del_end)
{
    string delim;
    size_t delim_len;

    string::const_iterator last = str_beg;
    string::const_iterator next = str_beg;
    while ((next = find_first_of(last, str_end, del_beg, del_end, FindDelim(delim))) != str_end) {
        delim_len = delim.size();

        output_str.push_back(string(&(*last), distance(last, next)));
        output_del.push_back(string(&(*next), delim_len));

        last = next + delim_len;
    }
    output_str.push_back(string(&(*last)));
}

inline void split_string(
    vector<string>         & output_str,
    vector<string>         & output_del,
    const string::const_iterator & beg,
    const string::const_iterator & end,
    vector<string>         & delims)
{
    split_string(output_str, output_del, beg, end, delims.begin(), delims.end());
}
inline void split_string(
    vector<string>         &  output_str,
    vector<string>         &  output_del,
    const string::const_iterator &  beg,
    const string::const_iterator &  end,
    vector<string>         && delims)
{
    split_string(output_str, output_del, beg, end, delims.begin(), delims.end());
}
```

---

Consider providing an *input iterator* interface for your tokeniser.  That will enable consumers to gather the tokens into a standard collection, or to use them in streaming fashion without unnecessary overhead.

---

You should understand the implications of `using namespace std;`.  I would advise you to steer clear of it at file scope.

---

<s>You assign to `FindDelim::out_delim` but never read from it - that suggests that it can be removed without changing the meaning.</s>

The `FindDelim::out_delim` member is a reference that allows modification of non-owned objects.  To me, I find that such references weaken the encapsulation of the class, and I prefer to avoid them (as evidenced by the fact I needed to edit my answer here).  Perhaps there's a way to limit the action-at-a-distance that's easily overlooked.  (I don't have a concrete suggestion here; perhaps some other answerer will propose an improvement).

---

I suggest using standard predicates instead of writing your own - `is_whitespace` is better written as `std::isspace` (you'll need to include `<cctype>`, of course) unless you really expect backspace in the input.

---

Although you *may* `return` *void-expression*`;` from a function that returns void, I would reserve this for use only in template functions that may or may not return void depending on their instantiation - not for functions that always return void.

---

Finally, please ditch the pointless read at the end of `main()` - it caused my run to hang waiting for input (which it won't get, in Emacs's compilation buffer...).  It's not portable to rely on it without including `<cstdio>`, anyway.

---

## Sample code

Here's an approach using `std::regex` that addresses the points above.  Its performance can obviously be improved, but I'd recommend doing that by swapping out the regex for a custom parser *without changing the interface*.  You can see how the iterators provide flexibility and allow the use of standard algorithms:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <regex>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    const std::string expr{"[X] += 2 + 100 + 32 + 231 -= 123 + 532"};
    const std::regex separator{"\\+=|-="};

    std::vector<std::string> tokens;
    std::copy(std::sregex_token_iterator(expr.begin(), expr.end(), separator, -1),
              std::sregex_token_iterator(),
              std::back_inserter(tokens));

    // Remove spaces
    static int (*const is_space)(int) = std::isspace;
    for (auto& s: tokens)
        s.erase(std::remove_if(s.begin(), s.end(), is_space), s.end());

    // Print result:
    std::copy(tokens.begin(), tokens.end(),
              std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, "\n"));
}
```

I verified that the output is identical to your original.

Comment: "**_You assign to FindDelim::out_delim but never read from it - that suggests that it can be removed without changing the meaning._**" I am reading from it. Look at `line 50`. I am creating there a `string delin` Next look at `line 55` I am passing that string through reference as constructor parameter. After that, in `FindDelim` function object I am comparing two strings; first is a fragment of input expression, second is currently examined delimiter. If match is found, delimiter is copied to the `out_delim`, and therefore `out_Delim` is a reference, it can be accessed inside higher scope.

Comment: Ah, sorry - I missed that it is a reference member!  (I tend to avoid modifiable reference members in my own code - they tend to hide unexpected action, as this did for me!).